# Question on Chapter 2 Riemannian Manifolds by John M. Lee (Tensors)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Currently I am proving Lemma 2.1. in the above mentioned book. One should show, that the space of multilinear mappings $$\underbrace{V^* \times \cdots \times V^*}_l \times \underbrace{V \times \cdots \times V}_k \to V$$ for some finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $T_{l + 1}^k(V)$, the set of $k$-times covariant and ($l + 1$)-times contravariant tensors. I defined $$\varphi(f): \underbrace{V^* \times \cdots \times V^*}_{l+1} \times \underbrace{V \times \cdots \times V}_k \to \mathbb{R}$$ by
$$\varphi(f)(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^{l + 1}, X_1,\dots,X_k) := \omega^{l+1}\left(f(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^l, X_1,\dots,X_k)\right)$$
for some multilinear map $f$. Then linearity is easy to show. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, it would suffice to prove that $\varphi$ is injective. But somehow I am not able to show this. We consider the kernel of $\varphi$, i.e. the elements $f$ for which we get the zero tensor. But I do not see how I could conclude that $f = 0$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me,  I know why $\varphi$ is injective from the answer below. But I don't  why $\varphi$ is surjective. Could you tell me? Thanks.

Comment: @lanse7pty For finite-dimensional vector spaces injectivity, surjectivity and bijectivity are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you. For example, $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,  f(x)=(x,0)$, obviously, it is injective but not surjective.  I think the equivalency of them need that they have same dimension. But I also can't get the dimension of $T_{l + 1}^k(V)$ and ...

Comment: @lanse7pty Both real vector spaces above have the dimension $n^{(l + 1)k}$ if $\operatorname{dim}V = n$. This follows from the coordinate representation of a [multilinear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ satisfies $\varphi (f) = 0$. Then we have

$$\omega^{l+1}(f(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^l, X_1,\dots,X_k))=0$$

for all $\omega^1, \cdots, \omega^{l+1}$ and $X_1, \cdots, X_k$. Since $\omega^{l+1}$ is arbitrary, we conclude that

$$f(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^l, X_1,\dots,X_k) = 0$$

for all $\omega^1, \cdots, \omega^l$ and $X_1, \cdots, X_k$ and thus $f=0$. Thus $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem was that I did not fully realize that $\omega^{l+1}$ may vary. +1